# Get The Time In Php For Chat

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

UPDATE:

I fixed the problem.

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
$time = $date->format('g:i a');
echo $time;
```

Thankyou

Comment: *"I have looked everywhere, and I cannot find the answer"* [apparently not](https://www.google.com.au/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=php+time&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=vXBKVoaOIYismAXOg6zQBg) unless you can explain why the first few results don't work

Comment: Just a note, the "time" you get back will likely be the server's time which is often not the local time of whomever is chatting. You would likely want to send back a timestamp and then use javascript (which can see the local timezone to the user) to display the time. Without more information, like how your chat is setup, there isn't much we can do other than point you to the generic [time](http://php.net/time) and [date](http://php.net/date) functions.

Comment: Yes. I understand now.

Comment: Wish you had kept the original question and answered to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
echo "Bob at " . date('h:i', time()) . " - hello! \n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the time with [PHP date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
date ( 'H:i' );
```

you might need to set timezone first if you get a warning

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```